# Relative sizing for games in java

Tags: java

I want to make a simple game that when you maximize/resize, the layout stays the same and the components resize. What is the best way to approach this?

Comment: Use a LayoutManager (google is your friend).

Comment: What sort of code are you using to design the game already?  Are you drawing everything with a `JPanel`, or are you doing something more sophisticated?

Comment: I think I will be using a JPanel, please note this game will be using moving components.

Comment: Separate your view from your model. Your model should have its own _constant_ units and then your view should translate between model-space and screen-space.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15844070/components-disappear-after-resizing-jpanel/15844981#15844981) that uses a custom PropertionalLayoutManager to manage the changes to the size of the main frame

Answer (score 2):

I have an example of how I've done it using a scale parameter:

https://github.com/Mataniko/Space-Invaders

https://github.com/Mataniko/Space-Invaders/search?q=scale&ref=cmdform

This might not be the best way to do it depending on your game but it's a good starting point.